# preg_match multiple help?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
<?PHP
    $string = "[test]aaaaa[/[test][test]bbbb[/test][test]cccc[/test][test]ddd[/test]";
    echo $string . "<br>";
    preg_match("/\[test\].*?(\[\/test\])/i", $string, $m);
    print_r($m);
?>
```

how to get value aaaaa and bbbb in multiple from capture [test] and [/test] ?

Comment: I think the first tag pair in the string to search has a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/\[test\](.*?)\[\/test\]/i", $string, $array);
```

`$array[1]` has what you want.

Answer (score 1):

non regex way

```
$string = "[test]aaaaa[/test][test]bbbb[/test][test]cccc[/test][test]ddd[/test]";
$s = explode('[/test]',$string);
foreach ($s as $v){
    if( strpos( $v,"[test]" )!==FALSE ){
        $t=explode("[test]",$v);
        print $t[1]."\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
aaaaa
bbbb
cccc
ddd
```